# Unexpected token =

Tags: node.js

I'm unsure as to what could cause this error in Node.js, as I've never seen it before and cannot find another issue online.

```
Message:
    Unexpected token =
Stack:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>     (/Projects/api/test/integration/models/article.js:3:15)
```

The file that is causing the error has the following contents:

```
'use strict';

var Article = require('../../../models/article')
```

Why in the world would `=` cause an error?

Edit 1 - adding the article.js that is being required:

```
'use strict';

class ArticleModel {

  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.options = options
  }

}

module.exports = ArticleModel
```

Comment: it may not have found the file.  Sometimes it gives you an error message and is interpreted rather unusually

Comment: Don't you need a semi-colon at the end?

Comment: Is that the entire file? If a file is not found, you should get an error like this: `Error: Cannot find module `. Also, is it possible that it's some weird unicode = like character?

Comment: I've tried erasing the `=` and retyping it. I've tried `require` on a different file, and gotten the same error.

Comment: Can you show us `article` module (not a test)?

Comment: @vp_arth added it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I know only js, which doesn't know classes :( Are you sure, there are default argument values?

Comment: I mean: try to replace `= {}` by `if(typeof options=='undefined')options={};`

Comment: @vp_arth yes that removes the error - but ES6 allows for default parameters. I'm running Node.js 5.0.0.

Comment: I can't to help here :)

Comment: @vp_arth put your comments as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

node.js 5.0 does not support all ES6 features yet.  In particular, it does not yet support default parameters.

So this line:

```
constructor(options = {}) {
```

is what is causing the error with the `=` assignment.

See [this table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for which features are supported in node.js 5.0.

---

You can replace the default parameter assignment with the old fashioned method:

```
constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
}
```

Comment: Spot on. OP, use the suggested method, or use `babel-core` to get support for this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your current Node.js distribution doesn't support default parameter values.

You should remove it:

```
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }
```

Or, try to play with `--harmony` runtime flag.

---

According to [this link](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) `--harmony` can not to help, this feature doesn't implemented in node5.0 at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Node v5.7.0 and can enable default parameters using this option:
--harmony-default-parameters

Answer (score -1):

The error is on the 3rd line of article.js.

Comment: The contents at the bottom of the question is the article.js file that is giving it an error. The test file is called `test/integrations/models/article.js`, which loads `../../../models/article.js`.

Comment: anyway, search a bug inside original module